# querying mixed language elasticsearch field via kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have documents with a mixed-language field.  What is the best way to store the information in elasticsearch such that it can best be queried via kibana:

Option 1:  add synthetic field via ES mapping per the advice of the manual (http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/mixed-lang-fields.html)

I have been having some difficulty in having kibana handle these fields appropriately.

Option 2:  create multiple mappings, one per language, then store the documents in the same index, but with a different doc_type.

Option 3:  create multiple indices (each with its respective mapping), one per language, then store documents in the appropriate index.

Options 2 and 3 keep the redundant storage down, and ensure that only the correct analyzer is executed for a particular field.  However, these two options require running a language classifier prior to creating the document.

Option 4:  Use one index / doc_type, but update the mapping before creating each document.

This option seems to be a case of pre-mature optimization, and is probably not worth pursuing.

Option 5:  ?!?